# How do you determine static statistics of creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, monster-design

I am writing stat blocks for creatures in a D&D module that I am working on with a friend. I am the designer, not the DM and I need to determine static stats for some creatures.

Exempli gratia, a gelatinous cube that I am working out has an HD of d10 and 20 Constitution at level 2, so it has 2d10 + 10 Con mod. From the information, I determined that its static HP would be 26. Am I right?

Can anyone tell me in-depth how static statistics for creatures are determined; not just their HP but for their whole stat block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the rules for creating monsters are on pages 273 - 283 of the Dungeon Master's Guide. That said, to determine a creature's static hit points, you simply calculate the average hit points.

A 2HD creature with a hit die of d10 and a Constitution of 20 would have 21 hit points on average: the average roll of 2d10 is 11 (5.5 per die), and a Constitution of 20 gives another 5 hit points per HD.

Comment: Does this average also apply to static damage as well, such as that of a melee attack, an ability or trait that the creature may have that deals damage?

Comment: Yes, static damage numbers listed in stat blocks are simply the average damage of the attack. This is clear from looking at the entries in the Monster Manual.

Comment: I guess the question's estimate of 26 hp came from maximizing the first hit die, like a PC would. This answer could be improved by calling out this misconception directly, and/or citing the relevant passage from the DMG.